# Output @sys.date_time value to the Sheet

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

First of all, when I input "Tomorrow noon", the system output "2019-09-21T12:00:00+08:00"(parameter: whattime). When I inputted the word – "Tomorrow noon", the system would convert it into `whatime: {"date_time": ""2019-09-21T12:00:00+08:00"}`.

Second, there's only time to show it up after inputting a period of data. (you can check this picture I posted).
How do I fix my codes?

```
function saveDataHandler(agent){
    const{
      namelist, howmanypeople, whattime, forhere
    } = agent.parameters;
    const data = [{
      Name:namelist,
      Number:howmanypeople,
      Time:whattime[1],
      Forhere:forhere
    }];
    axios.post('.....it's about API', data);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: [Edit] to 1.Show apps script code 2.Apps script stackdriver logs 3. Why `[1]` in `Time:whattime[1]`? Why not just `Time:whattime`?

Comment: When I inputted the word – "Tomorrow noon", the system would convert it into whatime: {"date_time": ""2019-09-21T12:00:00+08:00"}. So, it's only this data which couldn't be able to store in the Sheet. That's why it's not suitable for your answer and also I'd tried it before. However, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `whattime` value is `whatime: {"date_time": "2019-09-21T12:00:00+08:00"}`, you should  access `date_time` in `whatime` before sending it.

```
const{
      namelist, howmanypeople, whattime:{"date_time":dt}, forhere
    } = agent.parameters;//modified 
const data = [{
      Name:namelist,
      Number:howmanypeople,
      Time:dt.toString(),//modified
      Forhere:forhere
    }];
```

OR

```
const{
      namelist, howmanypeople, whattime, forhere
    } = agent.parameters;
const data = [{
      Name:namelist,
      Number:howmanypeople,
      Time:whattime["date_time"].toString(),//modified
      Forhere:forhere
    }];
```

#### To read:

- [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)